# jquery selector from html comment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little big problem. I try almost everything and I am not able to select an element from table if I know some commented text. I think that this is not possible. For example

```
<table id='table1'>
   <tr>
     <td>
      Some text
     </td>
     <td>
     <!-- someid="id301" -->
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
      Some next text
     </td>
     <td>
     <!-- someid="id303" -->
     </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

OK. So I only know for example this value someid="301" or someid="302". And I need to get parent  element for example to change color of this  by jquery. I really tested everything and I am not able to get tr element. Thank you for your help.

Comment: there is a jQuery plugin, thank google!

Comment: What you Really want to do ?

Comment: you want to target specific comment's parent regarding comment's id?

Comment: Hello. No I need to change color of tr element if I know someid="302". So to change color of second row. Thanks

Comment: Why have you added identifiers to comments, rather than elements?

Comment: Why are you using the comment and not an attribute (class or id) on an element?  It doesn't make sense to use HTML comments in this way when there are simple, standard methods available that will actually take less effort.  That's the essence of jQuery.PHP.Magento.com's comment above.

Comment: A Wolff has a brilliant solution if you haven't yet seen it. If it is too complicated, or doesn't give you exactly what you need, *let him know with a comment* and I'm sure he (or someone else) will provide a more broken down example. +1

Comment: You can use data-attribute to put your id in the td, like <td data-someid="id301">...</td> and then select it like : $('td[data-someid="id301"]').css('background-color', 'green');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the content of each TDs but honestly i don't see any purpose for that:

```
var someValue = 'someid="id303"';

$('table').find('td').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 8 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(someValue) != -1;
}).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: That's actually pretty cool... +1

Answer (score 1):

If you need that string to setup something, then generally it is not a good practice to put that string in comment.

I would suggest you to put that someid as a data attribute in td element

```
<td data-someid="id301">...</td>
```

then you can access it by $td.attr("data-someid") or even use it in jQuery selector

```
$('td[data-someid="id301"]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you but the script is automatically generated so I am not able to change comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Comments() Plug-in or

```
<input type="hidden" id="id301">
```

Comment: Add `" "` around hidden and id301

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com this is optional depending DOCTYPE

Comment: @A.Wolff , sure but its bad practice.

Comment: Hello. Hmm...I don't understand this. How this help me. I need to change color of tr element if I know someid="302". So to change color of second row. Thanks

Comment: I am not able to change <!-- someid="id301" --> this to html input hidden.... this comment is automatically generated...Thank you

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Ya, you are right!

Comment: @user1223484 why would you automatically generate a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var tableId = 'table1';
var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
// Pattern for searching for the string like someid="id[somenumbersinarow]"
var pattern = /someid=\"id[0-9]+\"/
// Pattern for searching for numeric value
var numericPattern = /[0-9]+/
var innerHTML, tr;
for (var i = 0, amountOfTrs = trs.length; i < amountOfTrs; i++){
    tr = trs[i];
    innerHTML = tr.innerHTML;
/* Searching for the comment with "someid" string, turning it into string 
(it will be the only string because there will be a single element in the array), 
then again search for numbers, convert to string and try to parse it) */
    console.log(parseInt(innerHTML.match(pattern).toString().match(numericPattern)));
}
</script>
```

This script properly works if there's only one comment per the TR element

pattern is a regular expression object. It can be used with modifiers such as g (search for ALL the matches in the text), for instance: /[0-9]+/g. In this case you'll get an array which may have a length greater than 1.

In the example I provided the modifier isn't used, so toString() method will return a string in this case. If you go further and try to get a number by another pattern, then you can use parseInt to extract number (id)

Be aware that if the match() method doesn't find anything it returns null, so before invoking function like in my example, you should either strongly know that this comment exists or perform some additional check.